# Drawing a PNG Graphic to a Canvas without transparency?

Tags: delphi, drawing, png, delphi-xe2, transparent

I've seen many questions asking how to draw transparent images, but my case is quite the opposite. I have a `TPicture` where I load any file type, including `PNG`. I then read `TPicture.Graphic` and call `Draw` directly in a `TBitmap`'s canvas. However, when the image is drawn, it carries over the transparency of the original `PNG` image.

The current code is very simple, just...

```
MyPicture.LoadFromFile(SomeFilename);
MyBitmap.Canvas.StretchDraw(SomeRect, MyPicture.Graphic);
```

Now the issue is that the canvas which I'm drawing to already has an image, and this PNG is being drawn over a portion of it. When the PNG has a transparent background, normally it appears white. However, since it's directly drawing a transparent graphic to the canvas, it keeps those areas transparent.

How can I draw a `PNG` Graphic directly to a canvas without its original transparency while using only the canvas drawing methods? I don't want to create too many graphic objects and draw too many times, hence the reason I only have 2 lines of code above. I'm hoping there's a way I can do something like `BitBlt` with some special mechanism for this purpose.

Comment: Your question is ill-formed. If you don't want transparency, you need to say what you want in its place. Transparency is an absence of colour. What do you want instead?

Comment: @David, I edited my question for that exact reason just as you put that comment. I added more info about why it needs to be transparent, and why I don't want to create too much code to do it.

Comment: Can't you fillrect that portion just before you draw?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz I must slap myself in the face for not thinking of that. Simple. Adds only 1 line of code (other than preparing the brush/pen). I'd accept that as an answer.

Comment: @Jerry - I already commented and upvoted on the answer which I believe is correct. It only misses the implementation, no big deal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only method pre-built in Delphi XE2 has a defect and doesn't work properly. Instead, draw whitespace, or whatever background you desire, to a blank canvas. Then draw the transparent image on top.

In case you aren't drawing onto a blank canvas, you can call `FillRect` method of the bitmap canvas for the region you're planning to draw the png.

Comment: In any case the logic is valid. By definition a transparent image has no background, you can draw it on any color you'd like.

Comment: The language and code (which I just removed) are irrelevant. This is the trivial way to solve your problem. I do sometimes wonder why people seem to fixate on code and language. Learn lots of languages. Learn tens of languages. Learn different views of the world. Learn to read and absorb ideas in prose rather than code.

Comment: @Jerry, seems there is not.

Comment: Jerry - I agree with @TLama. I think that artifact can be due to a defect in VCL code.